# Django Image is not added to media folder

Tags: django, apache, media

So the thing is that in production code with media files is not working (image of model is not added there). If you need some details please write! Thank you for your help )

project configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        Alias /static /home/artashes/multi/static
        <Directory /home/artashes/multi/static>
                 Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/artashes/multi/media
        <Directory /home/artashes/multi/static>
                 Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/artashes/multi/multisad>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/artashes/multi/multisad/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/artashes/multi python-home=/home/artashes/multi/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup django_app
</VirtualHost>
```

settings

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

By the way I am using apache2 with linode server

Comment: review the error log and access logs when you submit any media to the server

Comment: I am not getting any errors, just image is not added to media